# frontier_exploration waiting for transform warning

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am following one of the tutorials on Roswiki of frontier_exploration
when i launch the global.launch file
i receive a ros msg saying "Please use the 'Point' tool in Rviz to select an exporation boundary"
followed by a warning msg as "Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101399 timeout was 0.1."

but when i open the Rviz and try to use the points tool i am unable to select the points, it also shows that there is no tf data.

i am unable to make it work plz help me i really need help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227864/frontier_exploration-waiting-for-transform-warning/) by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the problem was with the launch files i was launching the global_map launch file which waits for a map from map_server then i used the no_global_map launch file edited its yaml syntax to the map and sensor setting which i required and it started working

---

Originally posted by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) with karma: 62 on 2016-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0